# Why does `git remote` not list anything on my git-svn repo?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

After doing `git svn init -s <url to repo>`, `git remote` doesn't list any remotes. Why?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because a subversion "remote" is not a real git remote. Try `git svn info` to see the remote information for the subversion repository.

Comment: ah ha. that is useful. the main problem i'm try to solve is described here, maybe you have something to add: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168411/how-does-git-svn-know-which-branch-to-dcommit-to