# How can I make git-svn get rid of remote branches that don't exist anymore?

Tags: git, git-svn

Is there a handy way to get my local git repo to forget about remote branches that have been deleted? `git svn fetch` doesn't "re-sync everything" like I hoped it might. My local repo was set up with using an import of the standard svn repo layout (`git svn -s …`).

related: [Why does `git remote` not list anything on my git-svn repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169017/why-does-git-remote-not-list-anything-on-my-git-svn-repo)

Comment: My first thought would be to just delete the files representing those branches, which are just little text files in `.git/refs/remotes`. But there's probably a more correct way than that, and I'm sure it would be possible to mess things up if you go poking around in the `.git` folder without really knowing what you're doing.

Comment: You'd also want to look at your `.git/config` file and delete any mention of them there.

Answer (score 15):

You can remove orphaned remote branches by executing the following commands:

```
git branch -d -r my_branch
rm -rf .git/svn/refs/remotes/my_branch
```

To remove all orphaned branches at once rather than one at a time, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7209462/149212).

Comment: I also had to do `rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/my_branch` for the branch not to be shown. Also, `rm -rf .git/svn/refs/remotes/origin/my_branch/` instead of `rm -rf .git/svn/refs/remotes/my_branch/` (note the `origin`). Any idea why?

Comment: To answer myself about the difference, I probably used `--prefix` when cloning, which is default behaviour from 2.0 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

On the first thought, I would suggest trying `git remote prune`. Excerpt from [documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html):

> prune
>
> Deletes all stale remote-tracking
>   branches under . These stale
>   branches have already been removed
>   from the remote repository referenced
>   by , but are still locally
>   available in "remotes/".
>
> With --dry-run option, report what
>   branches will be pruned, but do not
>   actually prune them.

I think this should also work with a remote called `svn`...

Comment: nope… git-svn doesn't store remotes in the standard way, and not in a handy abstraction of it either… there are no remotes, `git remote` has no output.

Comment: Although this does not work, it is relevant information to know that it doesn't