# Git-SVN using wrong credentials on Mac

Tags: macos, cocoapods, git-svn

I recently updated my password at work, the system forces updates every so often. And Git-SVN is doing something to cause the system to lock out.

I know it's Git-SVN because I'll stop using it for a couple days, and my system stops locking out. But when I start using Git-SVN I'll lock out again. I've recreated this problem a few times, so I'm very certain that it's Git-SVN. I'm the only one using Git-SVN and the only one getting this problem.

Something worth noting, I develop for iOS which uses the cocoapods package manager. One of the packages I use, is an in-house project that uses SVN. After the lock out retrieving this package does not work. It's only after running the following script, located here,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914681/git-svn-bulk-removing-orphaned-remote-branches/7209462#7209462

that I'm able to retrieve the package.

I'm staring at my keychain and there's not a whole lot of credentials to look through. I tried resetting my entire key chain to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

git svn should use the normal svn credentials store. So you probably still have the old password in `~/.subversion/auth/` or wherever it is stored on OS X.