# Listing svn remotes available for git rebase

Tags: git, svn

When trying to apply the updates from my Subversion server, how can I list remotes that are available to me for a `git rebase`? I'm asking because the "subversion remote" isn't listed when I run `git remote`...

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch -avv
```

The "subversion remote" isn't listed as a remote, because the way git svn interacts with the svn server is through a branch, not a remote. This is why we use "rebase" to update a branch to contain the contents of the subversion repository "branch."

Also see [Why does `git remote` not list anything on my git-svn repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169017/why-does-git-remote-not-list-anything-on-my-git-svn-repo/)